# Determine if the iPhone is in the US or Canada?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I have two questions. In my app, I am getting the GPS coordinates of friends. How can I determine if those friends are in the US/Canada?

The second question is to find out if the actual device is in the US/Canada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term for this is Reverse Geocoding. You want to have a look at the [MKReverseGeocoder class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and its sample code, this is Apple's solution for this. However, it requires you to display a map (which may or may not be what you want).

If you don't want the map then things get a little bit more complicated. See [Offline Reverse Geocoding at Country Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103878/offline-reverse-geocoding-at-country-level) and [Techniques for offline reverse geocoding on a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589519/techniques-for-offline-reverse-geocoding-on-a-mobile-device).

Comment: I looked at the class. I get the GPS coords from an address using it. How does that help determine if the person is in the US or another country like England, Egypt?

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: You determine the GPS coords using CoreLocation, and then query the [placemark](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKPlacemark) using the MKReverseGeocoder class. The placemark tells you which country you're currently in.

Comment: Of course, note that this only works with a network connection. So you're probably out of luck in the cellar. But then you wouldn't get coordinates either (with no GPS and no WiFi).

Comment: CocoaDev, the solution I have provided should work. Try this option

Comment: I'm looking into the placemark.     NSString *country = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey];

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: Why not simply use `placemark.country`, or maybe even better `placemark.countryCode` ? The later will always be the same, not matter which language the user is using (I'm not sure whether `placemark.country` is localized or not, Apple doesn't say).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Reverse Geocoding API of google to get the address corresponding to the coordinates and extract the country details from the response's address_components.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

Comment: The MKReverseGeocoder class uses Google maps. Also note that when you want to the [Google Maps Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) you need to obey to the [terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html). The most problematic one is this: *geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited*

Comment: @DarkDust:+1.. Thanks for pointing out that. IMO, this particular condition  makes no sense.

Comment: It does make sense because when you display the Google map, the term "Google" is overlayed and thus the user clearly sees where the data is coming from. So that's a kind of advertising for Google which they demand for using the service free-of-charge. I think it's a fair deal, although of course I'd also like to use the service without necessarily displaying a map.